# How to get the raw text of SVG files with google scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, blob

Trying to extract SVG file text but it comes out gibberish.

I'm have 30+ SVG files, in one google drive folder, and I am trying to extract their text (as html / xml) and save it in one big docs/text file.
Everything is working but - the text extracted is gibberish, and not the content of the SVG file.

```
// Google Apps Scripts
var files =[];
var myFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXXXXXXXXXXCew9Rrii0eSHo');
var filesInFolder = myFolder.getFiles();  

while (filesInFolder.hasNext()){  
    var nextFile = filesInFolder.next(); 
    files.push(nextFile)
}
var mergedText = ''; 
var charSet = 'ISO-8859-1' //charSet = 'UTF-8' // `tried that too 
for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++){ 
   var txt = files[i].getBlob().getDataAsString(charSet); 
   mergedText += txt 
} 
var doc = DocumentApp.create('All my SVG files'); var text = 
doc.getBody().editAsTex`t();text.insertText(0, mergedText)
```

trying to get SVG, formatted as `html/xml`, but I get something like :

```
x��� | e���'� �M�$!b�Tl�����P� �o��W�N=�y`?=={�Cή�d��&t0��w�"�%�4���<�{k$;���|ޯ� ����ٝg~�����
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. So can you provide a sample SVG file? By this, I would like to try to replicate your situation. Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Are you sure that the blob you are getting is [a text/xml format like you're expecting?](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getascontenttype) Perhaps `files = DriveApp.getFilesByType(MimeType.SVG)` ([see here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type)) would work better; or [`getAs('text/plain')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24366253/how-to-read-a-txt-file-copy-the-content-into-a-new-file-and-replace-certain-co)

Comment: I tried to reproduce your code with this SVG file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J1ktoz62qBZI7-0csnC1aU-LXDkZVFHB/view?usp=sharing It worked as intended. Please check if it also does for you - if not, there must be a problem with your SVG files. In this case try to convert the files one by one - to see where the problem is.  I modified in your code editAsTex`t(); to editAsText(); but I assume that this was only a typing mistake and not the reason for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much, you're right the code actually works. The problem was that there were other google doc files (that are not in plain text) in the folder and that was what made the gibberish text. 
I managed to work it out from your answers.